# Tablesorter theme, changing row background on button click

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter, css-tables

I am using tablesorter 2.0 and I have been trying to override the css theme when a button is clicked, but I can't seem to get anything going.  I tried to add a little css to the theme file, but I think another attribute is overriding it.  What I want to do is **change the background color of a row of a certain class**.

If anyone can check this out and tell me where to add the class and the attribute to this file, it would be appreciated.

Here is the theme file for tablesorter:

```
table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius:3px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
    background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(desc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
background-color: #5B5781;
}
```

Here is the jquery css I use to change the row (it's a callback from a $.post() call):

```
function(){
            $("#row_"+id).css("background-color", "orange");
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with TR having background-color.

Your code works but you have to realize that you specified that TD have a background-color of #FFF. You are changing the TR's BG color, but TD's color is on top of it.